# How to disable automatic 'mark as read' in Mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

Mutt automatically remove 'N' flag from e-mail after it was opened. I don't want to mark this flag again after I saw content of mail. It would be better to override Mutt 'mark as read' behavior only when I enter specific command or particular rule applied i.e. content has been seen over 10s.

How to disable Mutt automatic 'N' flag removal ?
Is it possible to apply rules to trigger 'mark as read' ?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this? I'd like to disable that too :)

Comment: I didn't. When I want to keep e-mail unread to do something with it in future I simply change its state to new by typing 'N' after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The [imap_peek](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#imap_peek) option might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. Disabling this option cause mutt not to sync in real time, synchronization with IMAP server is performed on folder change or sync-mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a good solution to this as well.

Here is one (imperfect) solution that I tried:

```
macro index <return> "<previous-unread><next-unread><enter><set-flag>N"  "go to unread message and mark as new"
macro pager j "<next-unread><set-flag>N" "j- marking emails as new"
macro pager k "<previous-unread><set-flag>N" "k- marking emails as new"
```

This kinda works if you don't care about trampling over the old flag. (eg: if you are already using `unset mark_old` anyways)

Another thing that is possible is to `set read_only` in muttrc- but obviously there are huge limitations here.